# Move files between Azure and S3/Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

Is it possible to copy files between Azure and S3/Glacier, without going via an intermediary PC or VM. The use case is that we have multiple Sql Server Backups going onto Azure. We'd now like to copy a single monthly backup from Azure onto S3/Glacier for longer term disaster recovery. We're talking about ~5T/month

We don't want to pull 5T over our network and then push 5T back onto AWS, so we could run a tool from an Azure or AWS VM, but I was hoping that someone would have solved this already by providing a service to go Azure->AWS without the intermediary.

Apologies if pricing detail isn't permitted but I thought I'd demonstrate why Cloudsfer wouldn't work for us, although their service looks interesting. 60T Storage on glacier for a year with 5T going in per month costs $311/month (June 2017). Whereas transfer alone using Cloudsfer would be $3750/month. So storing the data is 1/12 of the cost of copying the data, that doesn't sound right.

I have no association with MS, Amazon or Cloudsferand I've let them know this question is here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, please edit your question to add more details. Do you want to mirror files between Azure storage and AWS storage without any kind of VM?

[AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) is a service you should look at. You might have to write a little bit of code, but it would run on AWS managed infrastructure. I think this will work.

Someone probably makes a service that will do it for you, if you pay them - a quick search found [Cloudsfer](http://www.cloudsfer.com/) which may or may not do what you want.

Otherwise, you use the public API for the service you're interested in. [S3 API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html), [Glacier](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/amazon-glacier-api.html). You need to run code for this.

There will also be plenty of different libraries or methods to access S3 made by others. There's also the [AWS Storage Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/details/), which does require a VM to be run, but makes accessing S3 easy.

Comment: I've edited my question to give the use case detail

Comment: If it's just files then use the data pipeline I suggested above. If you want to copy live from that database to a database in AWS you can use the AWS database migration service. The fallback method may be to spin up a t2.medium VM, do the copy, then turn the VM off.